# WS-Security issue

Tags: web-services, spring-ws, spring-integration

I'm trying to call a web service that uses Axis2 and SOAP 1.2 (axis 2 only) using Spring-integration and Spring-ws-core. The issue is that it returns an error:

```
15:15:14,128 TRACE SaajUtils:184 - SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Fault1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway#14683c0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:118)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at com.csc.billingux.WebServiceClient.sendRequesttoService(WebServiceClient.java:40)
    at com.csc.billingux.rest.AccountServiceAdapter.accountService(AccountServiceAdapter.java:47)
    at com.csc.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does not contain required Security header
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    ... 37 more
```

What my analysis is that it is using SOAP 1.3 instead of 1.2. I have provided even the configuration for specifying the SOAP version 1.2:

```
<beans:bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">     
    <beans:property name="soapVersion">         
    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>  
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Do I need to include any specific jar (specific jar for axis 2) so that it uses SOAP 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the stack trace. This is the key line

```
Incoming message does not contain required Security header
```

It's nothing to do with SAAJ or SOAP.

Comment: Indeed, AFAIK. there is not SOAP 1.3

Comment: ok so what might be thereason for this error am i missing some jars

Comment: You need to add a security header. Try googling WS-Security (take a deep breath first)

Comment: If you can help in giving some specific link which adds security header in spring configuration